# Angular 5 + How to move the cursor character by character using keyboard left/right options in IE 11

Tags: javascript, angular, cursor, internet-explorer-11, ag-grid

I am using Angular 5 with Ag-Grid Enterprise Addition. I am using IE11 browser. Unfortunately in the grid, the cursor gets stuck and not moving to next characters in the input box using keyboard left/right options. So, I thought of explicitly moving the cursor to next characters. I am using Javascript range for that. I am getting the error at this line document.getSelection().addRange(range). Please find the below code of the custom NumericComponent ,screenshot of input box and error. I am not sure if this is the right approach. Can anyone guide me how to fix this issue ?

```
<input #input  id="numericinput" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" (keydown)="onKeyDown($event)" [(ngModel)]="value" (dblclick) = "$event.target.select()">
              <button (click)="clear()" style="position:absolute;top:5px;right:2px;cursor:pointer;color:grey;background-color:white;border:none;">
                <span>&#10060;</span>
              </button>

onKeyDown(event): void {
        var key = event.which || event.keyCode;
        if(key === 37 || key === 39){
          let error ;
          event.stopPropagation();                      
          let inputDocument = document.getElementById('numericinput');    
          let range = document.createRange();
          range.collapse(true);        
          range.setEnd(inputDocument.firstChild, 0);          
          range.setStart(inputDocument.firstChild, this.input.element.nativeElement.value.length);          
          document.getSelection().removeAllRanges;          
          document.getSelection().addRange(range);                          
        }
        if (!this.isKeyPressedNumeric(event)) {
            if (event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();
        }

    }
```

[image]

Comment: Try to refer this example. https://textuploader.com/1dr22 It is able to get and set cursor position in textbox in IE 11. You can check the code and try to modify it as per your own requirement to work with arrow keys. Ref taken from https://www.webdeveloper.com/d/74982-how-to-setget-caret-position-of-a-textfield-in-ie

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT  Hi, i tried to use it but document.selection is undefined. I cannot get it's value .Can you please advise ? I am using angular 5

Comment: Did you directly try to run the example in IE 11? It is working fine on my side and able to get and set cursor position. You can provide your testing steps. we will again try to test it and check the result.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the support. I resolve it using input.setSelectionRange

Comment: From your last comment, It looks like you had found the solution for your issue. I suggest you to post your solution as an answer and try to mark your own answer as an accepted answer for this question after 48 hrs, when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the solution from which I achieved the task

```
var key = event.which || event.keyCode;
        var iCaretPos = 0;
        if(key === 37 || key === 39){   
            //Left or right       
          let inputDocument = document.getElementById('numericinput');
          const element : HTMLInputElement = <HTMLInputElement>inputDocument;
          event.stopPropagation();                                                  
          let selectionStart = 0;          
          if(key === 39 && this.iCaretPos < element.innerHTML.length+1){               
                selectionStart = this.iCaretPos;
                this.iCaretPos = this.iCaretPos +1;
          }else if(key === 37 && this.iCaretPos !== 0){               
                selectionStart = this.iCaretPos;
                this.iCaretPos = this.iCaretPos -1;
          }  
          let selectionEnd = this.iCaretPos;          
            if (element.setSelectionRange) {                                          
                element.focus();
                element.setSelectionRange(selectionStart, selectionEnd);
            }        
        }
```